# Tangent of Circles

Tags: geometry

$k_1$ is a circle with center $O_1$ and radius $r_1$. Similar for $k_2(O_2;r_2)$. $r_1 < r_2$.

$AB$ and $CD$ are tangent lines to $k_1$ and $k_2$.

[image: Image of the geometric situation]

Prove that $AP=DQ$.

Comment: is O, O1, O2 a line?

Comment: Yes, because O is the intersection of the 2 tangents of the circles

Comment: Hint: Calculate the ["power" of point $D$ with respect to $k_1$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_of_a_point), and the "power" of point $A$ with respect to $k_2$.

Comment: if you draw the 'inner tangential' from k1 to k2 (it passes close to AD) and say it intersects k1 at X and k2 at Y, does AX = YD?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Power of a Point Theorem](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/pythagoras/PPower.shtml) it follows that:

$AB^2=AQ \cdot AD$ and $DC^2 =AD \cdot DP$.

Now it is not hard to see that $AB=DC$. It follows that $AQ=DP$, that is $AP+PQ=PQ+DQ$. Hence $AP=DQ$.

Comment: Goed gedaan! +1

Comment: @imranfat Bedankt!